# androiddeployqt can't find ant error, but works with Qt Creator

Tags: qt

`Qt` 5.11. Mac OS X.

I'm trying to write automatic build script for `Jenkins`. Target platform: `Android armv7`.

`androiddeployqt` says me that it cannot find ant in `PATH`.

Yes, I did not install `Ant`.

But, it works somehow with `Qt Creator`. `Qt Creator` can build `APK`. Why so? It uses the same `androiddeployqt`, doesn't?

Do I really need to install ant (while Qt Creator does not need it)?

Answer (score 0):

Qt Creator uses undocumented `--gradle` option. Add it to your command.